# Sort an array of array based on the order of another array(Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays like this: `arr1 = [name1, name2,name3]` and `arr2 = [[name1,10], [name3,15], [name2, 20]]`. Now I want to sort the `arr2` based on the order of `arr1`. The order of `arr2` will change whenever order of `arr1` change. I try this:

```
hash_object = arr2.each_with_object({}) do |obj, hash| 
  hash[obj.name] = obj
end

arr1.map { |index| hash_object[index] }
```

But the result returned [nil, nil, nil]. I confused of this is the right way, and I only made mistake or are there another ways to solve my problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: If future, consider waiting longer before making a selection.  There's no rush, and a quick selection can discourage other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
=> ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
arr2 = [["name1",10], ["name3",15], ["name2", 20]]
=> [["name1", 10], ["name3", 15], ["name2", 20]]
arr2.sort_by { |e| arr1.index(e[0]) }
=> [["name1", 10], ["name2", 20], ["name3", 15]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I would do something like this:

```
arr2.sort_by { |element| arr1.index(element.first) }
```

Comment: Did you mean `sort_by`? I expected this to raise an exception (since `sort` takes two arguments), but it returned, `[["name2", 20], ["name3", 15], ["name1", 10]]`, which is not correct, of course.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You are right - especially because `sort_by` is usually faster than `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
arr2.values_at(*arr2.map { |str,_| arr1.index(str) })
  #=> [["name1", 10], ["name2", 20], ["name3", 15]]
```